# Set a List<Object> to a Model using MVVM

Tags: c#, list, mvvm

I need some help with my C# Code, using MVVM pattern.

I have a class with a reference for a List of another class (for better understanding, I renamed my fields):

```
class Class1
{
    /* ... */
    public string myString { get; set; }
    public List<OtherClass> otherclass { get; set; }
}
```

The class here named "otherclass" looks like the following:

```
class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(string str1, string str2, string str3)
    {
        Str1 = str1;
        Str2 = str2;
        Str3 = str3;
    }

    public string Str1 { get; set; }
    public string Str2 { get; set; }
    public string Str3 { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I have a ViewModel :

```
class MyViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Class1 class1;

    /* ... */
    public string myString
    {
        get { return class1.MyString; }
        set
        {
            class1.MyString = value;
            OnPropertyChange("MyString");
        }
    }

    // Issue here
    // private List<OtherClass> _mylist = new List<OtherClass>;
    public List<OtherClass> OtherClass
    {
        get { return class1.OtherClass; }
        set
        {
            // class1.OtherClass.Add(value);
            class1.OtherClass = value;
            OnPropertyChange("OtherClass");
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

When I need to fill my model, I just doing for example (in my code):

`myViewModel.myString = myvalue;`

Now, in my code I have a list with corrects values:

`myList = new OtherClass(value1, value2, value3)`.

When I want to add this list of object in my model, my model stay null for that entry:

`myViewModel.OtherClass = myList or myViewModel.OtherClass.Add(myList)`

I'm surely make something wrong... If someone can help me please ?

Comment: You need to create object instance for  `Class1` of  `class1` field in constructor. Without that you try to set property of null object.

Comment: ``class1 = new class1()`` are tried just to instantiate ``class1``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see code where your list is initialized, please try to change in `Class1`:

```
public List<OtherClass> otherclass  { get; set; }= new List<OtherClass>();
```

or add default constructor to Class1 where `List` is initialized. While it is not initialized it is not possible to add items to the `List`

```
public Class1()
{
  this.otherclass = new List<OtherClass>();
}
```

Comment: You mean `public List<OtherClass> otherclass { get; } = new List<OtherClass>();`

Comment: Sometimes ... we turn around for not much :) I added a default constructor, and i'm now able to add a list of my object inside my model. Thank's a lot !